# Pluggable switch statements

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, switch-statement

I have the following switch statement:

```
switch($post->post_type) {

    default:

        echo 'default';

<?php }
```

which in essence is about as basic as you can get. The `post->post_type` is simply a variable that will return a string depending on the post type of an item (WordPress).

What I'd like to be able to do is plug into the switch statement very similarly as someone would an array - like so:

```
function add_extra_fruits($fruits) {

$extra_fruits = array(
    'plums',
    'kiwis',
    'tangerines',
    'pepino melons'
);

// combine the two arrays
$fruits = array_merge($extra_fruits, $fruits);

return $fruits;
}
add_filter('add_fruits', 'add_extra_fruits');
```

using the `array_merge()` function.

I was given the following example to try:

```
switch ( true /* we're comparing a boolean, not the post type! */ ) {
    case has_action( "basey_loop_single_$post->post_type" ) :
        do_action( "basey_loop_single_$post->post_type" );
        break;

    default :
        // default post layout
}
```

but I'm not sure if this accomplishes what I'm after as passing an example action, like so:

```
function basey_loop_single_page_output() {
    echo 'test';
}
add_action('basey_loop_single_page', 'basey_loop_single_page_output');
```

does not return anything when the `$post->post_type` condition is met as it is specified. Anyone have an idea of how this could be approached? At its simplest, this is a core PHP question (about plugging into a switch statement), but obviously some of the lingo here is more geared towards WordPress.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you want to execute arbitrarily defined code based on the various values that `$post->post_type` can have? How will you define this arbitrary code? In functions? And (crucially) what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Did you try it with `"basey_loop_single_{$post->post_type}"`?

Comment: @prodigitalson Thanks - that along with my own stupidity did the trick :)

Comment: @Zach: is the (invalid) `<?php` in the first code fragment representative of the original code, or is its presence in the sample an oversight? Exactly how does the `add_extra_fruits` example correlate? Is `'add_fruits'` supposed to represent a post type? Are `add_filter` and `add_action` analogs? Why would a switch work while an array & loop wouldn't?

Comment: Hi @outis - sorry if there was any confusion on that. The `array_merge()` example was an example off what I was looking for with a `switch()` statement - @prodigitalson's suggestion worked though.